# КАК: сравнительный оборот или "в качестве"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

> И когда падёт последний император, то на место его заступит епископ:
>   на верховного священника теперь **начинают смотреть как на
>   единственного защитника, как на отца города**.

То, что сравнений парочка, на что-л. влияет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере оборот с как тесно связан со сказумым. Такие обороты  имеют значение отождествления или приравнивания. Запятая не нужна. Ср.: Вот почему она смотрела на землю как на юдоль скорби (Нов.-Пр.);

Answer (score 4):

Всё в порядке по поводу оборота, но меня смущает время. Мы как будто смотрим в будущее (когда падет...), и я бы написала так:

**И когда падёт последний император, то на его место  заступит епископ, и на верховного священника начнут смотреть как на единственного защитника, как на отца города.**

Comment: Верно подмечено! Автор все время жонглирует временами глагола — надо быть начеку!

Comment: Смысл авторского текста: на верховного священника **теперь** начинают смотреть как на единственного защитника, так как знают, что в будущем, когда падёт последний император, на его место заступит епископ.

Answer (score 2):

"В качестве" или нет, но если удалить из какого-нибудь предложения сравнительный оборот, то предложение должно остаться осмысленным. А здесь не останется. Значит, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, запятые стоят на своих местах. Священника считают защитником, отцом города. Это не сравнение.

А вот "когда... то" меня смущает; разве так можно писать?

Comment: Автор пишет; заказчику люб автор. В принципе - можно, но, как мы знаем, нет предела совершенству.